# MSN messenger contacts not showing up in pidgin with skype plugin

Tags: skype, contacts, windows-live-messenger, pidgin

I Have the skype plugin active on pidgin. It shows my skype contacts, but not my MSN contacts in the buddy list. I've only ever used MSN on pidgin or trillan, so with the recent merging of MSN with skype, I had to use the godawful skype program running in the background with pidgin. my MSN contacts show up in the skype client but how do I get them to show up in Pidgin?

Comment: The MSN service no longer exists.  I honestly don't understand the question for that reason. Additionally you can't even log into the MSN service it was merged into Skype over a year ago

Comment: Perhaps your MSN contacts needs to be moved to Skype. How would Pigdin know you have MSN contact if it only understands Skype. You'd have to make those contact Skype contacts (perhaps manually) for the Pidgin plugin to display them. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the newer [skypeweb plugin](https://github.com/EionRobb/skype4pidgin/tree/master/skypeweb#skypeweb-plugin-for-pidgin) for Pidgin.  Not only does it not need Skype running to work, but your MSN buddies should show up in your buddy list to talk to as well.